# Doobly Doo origins

Tags: meaning

Can someone please explain Doobly Doo (a Youtube slang for descriprion box below the video) origins in terms of its linguistic origin and author's motive adress a description box that way? I've seen a lot of sources which explain its meaning and first usage. But since it's an original phrase (is it?) I'd really like to know its language roots: does it root to a phrase with similar phonetics (doodle-doo)? I'm trying to figure out if it needs/can be adopted for other languages.

Would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Best regards, Anthony

**UPDATE:** Thank you Josh for providing a link to a previous thread on the pharase. It has a point: "doobly doo" sounds like a familiar idiom that's much older than that, used to name something you don't know the name of.'

If it's possible we'll wait for more opinions. Once again only its linguistic roots/possible cultural references etc. Not who and when it first used. The latter is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've heard this term used is on YouTube, but it was coined by YouTuber wheezywaiter, according to [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Doobly%20Doo). In his videos, he presents a whimsical and often excited (borderline twee) approach to lots of things, especially by use of funny special effects and nonsensically descriptive language. It seems like he coined the term as part of his YouTube persona.